# Any way to manage options in Open With dialog?

Tags: macos

Basically, my problem is that my `Open With` list looks like this for `.html` files

[image]

I want to be able to manage it somehow. For example, I often open those files with PHPStorm but that list is obviously full and I have to click `Other...` every time for eg. PHPStorm.

I'd like to be able to remove virtualized Internet Explorers, Word and simply to be able to manage it somehow. Any way to do that?

Comment: Do you wish to categorically remove all virtualized apps or remove things more selectively. The former should be far easier than the latter.

Comment: Rather selectively. For example I do not intend to open html via word or excel so I'd prefer more universal solution

Answer (score 2):

You can get rid of the Windows apps by unchecking the Share options in Parallels
[needs to be done for each VM]
[image]

To lose some of the others, I'd use [RCDefaultApp](http://www.rubicode.com/Software/RCDefaultApp/) - freeware - old but still working in Yosemite.

[image]

Might need to rebuild the Launch Services afterwards -
 <sub>as I did after taking the above picture ;-)</sub>

`/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Support/lsregister -kill -r -domain local -domain system -domain user`

Comment: That looks nice but, for example, `html` extension is unchecked under MS Word so I can't uncheck it. Also checked Extensions section but there I can only set default app

Comment: hmm… you're right - I can't get rid of word or excel either

Comment: There's some heavy Terminal stuff here - http://krypted.com/mac-os-x/lsregister-associating-file-types-in-mac-os-x/

Comment: I don't see it there, there's just how to register or unregister the default app. I want to be able to somehow manage associations between app and certain extensions so OSX won't offer me to open it with that app. Also I noticed your edit about rebuilding LS, what should it do? I don't see any difference, Default Apps still do not show `.html` under MS Word